# How to rotate label in Picker.Item under Picker in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I want to make a picker that is horizontally scrollable than vertical. To achieve that I did the following.

```
<Picker style={{width: 50, marginLeft: Device.width/2 - 32, transform: [{rotate: '90deg'}]}}
        selectedValue={this.state.currentSlide.toString()}
        onValueChange={this.onValueChange}>
    <Picker.Item label="1" value="0"/>
    <Picker.Item label="2" value="1" />
    <Picker.Item label="3" value="2" />
</Picker>
```

[image]
[image]

I want to rotate the text labels in the picker by 90 degrees. I have tried the following without any success.

```
<Picker.Item label="1" value="0" style={{rotation: 90}}/>
<Picker.Item label="1" value="0" style={{transform: [{rotate: 90}]}}/>
<Picker.Item label="1" value="0" style={{transform: [{rotate: '90deg'}]}}/>
```

Could you point me to the relevant style that will achieve this?

Comment: hi @Elayabharath did you get any solution for this .

Comment: @prateeakojha did you find a solution to this?

Comment: no have to use external library and add some forks